# Why am I getting the wrong result trying to solve the integration of $\ln x/x$ with the per parts method?

Tags: integration

I first calculated it using the substitution method and got the result $\frac 1 2\ln^2x+C$, $C\in \Bbb R$, but I am getting a wrong result attempting to use per parts on the same problem. Is there something I am missing? Is there a reason per parts cannot be applied here?

Comment: Is your integral $$\int \dfrac{\ln(x)}{x}~dx$$

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! Do you mean $\ln(x)$ ? In this case, note $\ln(x)=1\cdot \ln(x)$ for the integration by parts.

Comment: If it is Moo's integral, note that the derivate of $\ln(x)$ is $\frac{1}{x}$ , hence a substitution is successful.

Comment: It would help us if you edited your "by parts" attempt into your question

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the indefinite integration constant temporarily,

if you are attempting to apply $\int u\, dv = uv-\int v \, du$ here,

then with $u=\log_e(x)$ and $dv=\frac1x\, dx$, and thus  $v=\log_e(x)$ and $du = \frac1x\, dx$,

you would get $\int \log_e(x) \frac1x\, dx= \left(\log_e(x)\right)^2 -\int \log_e(x) \frac1x\, dx$ and rearranging  $$\int \frac{\log_e(x)}x\, dx = \tfrac12 \left(\log_e(x)\right)^2$$ as expected.

The indefinite integration constant comes into the $uv$ term so you can make this $\int \frac{\log_e(x)}x\, dx = \tfrac12 \left(\log_e(x)\right)^2+C.$

Answer (score 1):

Integration by parts brings :
$$
I := \int\frac{1}{x}\,\ln(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \ln^2(x) - \int\ln(x)\,\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
hence $2I = \ln^2(x)$ and the desired result.